# Every time I get the S-Bahn I hear "aussteck links/rechts"

Tags: german-to-english

I would like to know what they say in the S-Bahn that sounds like "aussteck links/rechts" but in the dictionary the closer to this I've found is:

```
Aussteck: unplugging
```

could someone explain what they are really saying?

Comment: I know it as `Austieg in Fahrtrichtung rechts/links` (Exit on left/right in the direction of train).

Comment: I wonder where you found "Aussteck" because it doesn't exist. The equivalent of "unplugging" would be "ausstecken".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They're saying „Ausstieg links/rechts“. `Ausstieg` is a noun derivative from the verb `aussteigen`. Basically they're just telling you on which side to get out, i.e. where the exit is.

Comment: »Ausstieg« = »Ausgang» = english »Exit«